# get iframe id according to position of user cursor

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have 2 iframe with contenteditable(true) in my webpage,
my question is how do i get iframe id according to position of cursor caret?

e.g : iframe1 and iframe2, if user cursor caret position in iframe2 then it will alert id frame2

i already tried following code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('iframe').on('change mouseup mousedown mouseout keydown', function(){

      var iframeID = $(this).attr('id');

      $(this).contents().unbind(); 

      $(this).contents().bind('click', function(){

          alert(iframeID);  
      });
   }); 

});
```

but it doesnt work

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use mouseenter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').mouseenter(function(h) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saq02L9o/

Comment: thanks Bommox for replying.. your code is working on iframe without designmode =on / without contentEditable(true) ,what i want is get iframeid based on user caret (not cursor) position on iframe contenteditable

Comment: Does this work if the user enters the iframe by tabbing (no mouse event)? I'm not planning to use this solution but now I'm curious if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use hover
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```js
$("iframe").hover(
  function() {
    alert('mouse in to ' + $(this).attr('id'))
  }, function() {
    //alert('mouse out of '+$(this).attr('id'))
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="foo">foo</iframe>
<iframe id="bar">bar</iframe>
```

Comment: thanks taesu for replying.. your code is working on iframe **without** designmode =on /  **without** contentEditable(true)
,what i want is get iframeid based on user caret (not cursor) position on iframe